# Compiling with -std=c++11 on Cygwin hides available system calls

Tags: c++, sockets, cygwin

I was investigating porting some code from older C++ to a more modern C++ version (e.g. C++ 11 or higher). And then I noticed some networking code not compiling when I added the compiler flag `-std=c++11`

Simplest MVCE example.  I'm on the latest Cygwin (literally installed today). `g++ --version` indicates version 7.3.0.

Take the following source file stripped down to almost nothing, but enough to show the issue I am about to explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int some_networking_code()
{
   addrinfo* addr = NULL;
   int flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
   return 0;
}
```

On a fresh install of Cygwin, the following command works just fine:

```
g++ foo.cpp -c
```

But now switch to compiling with C++11.

```
g++ foo.cpp -c -std=c++11
```

And the resulting compiler output is:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int some_networking_code()’:
foo.cpp:8:4: error: ‘addrinfo’ was not declared in this scope
    addrinfo* addr = NULL;
    ^~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:8:4: note: suggested alternative: ‘addr_t’
    addrinfo* addr = NULL;
    ^~~~~~~~
    addr_t
foo.cpp:8:14: error: ‘addr’ was not declared in this scope
    addrinfo* addr = NULL;
              ^~~~
foo.cpp:8:14: note: suggested alternative: ‘addr_t’
    addrinfo* addr = NULL;
              ^~~~
              addr_t
foo.cpp:9:16: error: ‘AI_NUMERICHOST’ was not declared in this scope
    int flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Debugging this, I take a peek at `/usr/include/netdb.h` and I see that the definition for `addrinfo` expects a macro called **__POSIX_VISIBLE** to be greater than or equal to `200112`.  There definition for AI_NUMERICONLY is wrapped within a similar block.

```
#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200112 && !defined(__INSIDE_CYGWIN_NET__)
struct addrinfo {
  int             ai_flags;             /* input flags */
  … <deleted for brevity>
#endif
```

Using the `-dM -E` switches, we can ask the compiler for what macros it's pulling in and filter to the POSIX_VISIBLE

```
$ g++ foo.cpp -c -dM -E | grep POSIX_VIS
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE 200809
```

Ok, that looks correct for traditional C++.  Let's inspect that for C++11 building:

```
$ g++ foo.cpp -c -std=c++11 -dM -E | grep POSIX_VIS
#define __POSIX_VISIBLE 0
```

`__POSIX_VISIBLE` is defined to be 0.  And that explains why we have the errors above.

It appears that `POSIX_VISIBLE` is getting defined by the header file at `/usr/include/sys/features.h` based on other defined macros.  But that's where I start to get confused.

Is this a bug in the Cygwin distro or its header files?  The way the compiler was built?  Or something else?  What's the appropriate workaround that won't impact building on Linux, Mac, BSD, and everywhere else?

Comment: You should ask on the cygwin mailing list. In case of bug it should be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a discussion on the [Cygwin mailing list](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-09/msg00085.html).  I had assumed that the absence of specifying `-std` on the command line would limit my build to not have access to modern C++ features. And that specifying `-std=c++11` or higher would enable these newer features.   That is actually incorrect. Newer versions of g++ default to something newer:

```
$ g++ -c foo.cpp -dM -E | grep cplus
#define __cplusplus 201402L
```

And using `-std` not only limits compiler feature behavior, but it disables the GNU built-in defines.  And Cygwin headers will hide several POSIX functions when GNU_SOURCE is not defined, including `getaddrinfo`.  I'm not sure if I agree with this configuration, but that's just how it works on Cygwin.  Avoiding `-std` is a better fix.

**Update**

While avoiding the use of `-std` is a great fix, earlier versions of g++ prior to 6.0 default to C++ 98 unless `-std` is used.  And there's still a lot of folks using pre 6.0 versions of g++.  There were a lot of Makefile hacks I investigated to sniff for C++ 11 support or compiler version such that `-std=c++11` is used conditionally, none of which are pretty. The workaround that seems to be universal to g++, Cygwin, and Clang is to use `-std=gnu++11`.

That is:

```
g++ foo.cpp -c -std=gnu++11
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new.html,
cygwin seems to aim at feature test macro compatibility with glibc.
`struct addrinfo` is used by `getaddrinfo`, which on glibc requires `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L`.

Indeed, the code compiles if you define the corresponding macro:

```
g++ -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L foo.cpp -c -std=c++11
```

or, alternatively, define the give-me-everything `_GNU_SOURCE`.

```
g++ -D_GNU_SOURCE foo.cpp -c -std=c++11
```